# Selecting a row when not null

Tags: mysql, select, null, where-clause

My table looks like this:

```
Client_ID  |  Date1   | Date2

 1         | 3/3/2015 | 3/13/2015
 2         | 3/4/2015 | 3/13/2015
 3         | 3/5/2015 | 3/14/2015
 3         | 3/5/2015 | 3/15/2015
 4         | 3/6/2015 | NULL
 4         | 3/7/2015 | 3/17/2015
 5         | 3/7/2015 | 3/17/2015
 6         | 3/7/2015 | NULL
```

I would like to get the client_IDs for which 'Date2' = 'Date1 + 10' days AND where no other Date2 is 'NULL' for that same client_ID.

So here, the expected results would be: Clients 1,3,5.
PS: 4 is not among the answer because it has one 'NULL'entry.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    Client_ID
from
    your_table
where
    Date2 is not null
    and Date1 = DATE_ADD(Date2, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: This won't work because your code will get client 4 and I don't want him because one of his record is NULL. (I would like where "no row of Date2 is null"..)

Comment: Client 4 has: Date2 is null

Comment: With your code, MySQL will select client_ID 4 's row where it is not null. With the right query client 4 should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Client_ID
FROM table AS a
WHERE a.Date2 - a.Date1 = 10
AND NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT '1'
FROM table AS b
WHERE b.Client_ID = a.Client_ID
AND b.Date2 Is Null
)
```